# Odoo: domain not working with a related field

Tags: python, odoo

i have a model "custom.products" which is connected to model "custom.branch.line" via a  one2many field "branch_line", I want to apply a domain filter on a related fields "branch1" & "branch2", I want it to show the qty of every product in each branch, but when i apply to domain to the related field it doesn't work, it just retrieves the 1st entry in the database table, my code is below

```
class CustomProduct(models.Model):
    _name = 'custom.product'
    _description = 'Product Record'

    branch_line = fields.One2many('custom.branch.line', 'product_id', string='Branch Lines', )
    branch1 = fields.Integer(string="branch 1", related="branch_line.qty", domain="[('branch_line.branch_id','=', 3)]", )
    branch2 = fields.Integer(string="branch 2", related="branch_line.qty", domain="[('branch_line.branch_id','=', 4)]", )

class CustomBranchLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'custom.branch.line'
    _description = 'Branch Line Record'

    branch_id = fields.Many2one('custom.branch', string='Branch')
    product_id = fields.Many2one('custom.product', string='Product')
    qty = fields.Integer(string="QTY", required=False, )
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use computed field to get the correct value for branch1 and branch2 fields:

```
branch1 = fields.Integer(string="branch 1",compute="_get_branch")
branch2 = fields.Integer(string="branch 2",compute="_get_branch")

@api.multi
def _get_branch(self):
    for line in self:
        line.branch1 = self.env['custom.branch.line'].search([('branch_id','=',3)],limit=1).qty
        line.branch2 =         self.env['custom.branch.line'].search([('branch_id','=',4)],limit=1).qty
```